# Python how to mock an ImportError when a package is imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, mocking

I have a package that has an optional library install. When the optional library is not present and the particular method is called a custom exception is raised saying the feature is not enabled without the optional package install. When the optional library is present then the method can be used.

I want to test both of these cases with pytest.

I am importing the libraries like:

```
try:
    import derp
except ImportError:
    pass
```

And then in the function checking if the library is installed by checking if the package is in `sys.modules`.

```
def my_feature_method():
    if 'derp' not in sys.modules:
        raise Exception('this feature requires the derp package to be installed')

    # do some stuff ...
```

I want to be able to test the case where the package *is* installed and *is not* installed in pytest.

**Edit**

At the moment I am using

```
with mock.patch.dict('sys.modules'):
    del sys.modules['derp']
    # run test
```

But this doesn't actually test that the `ImportError` is raised. I want this for coverage reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved this by changing my setup a bit:

```
def try_import(name, package=None):
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(name, package=package)
    except ImportError:
        pass

derp = try_import('derp')

if not globals()['derp']:
    raise Exception('this feature requires the derp package to be installed')
```

This means two things:

1. I can test the `try_import` function seperately.
2. I can simply patch the name like `mock.patch('__main__.derp', None)`

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the `sys.path` to prevent `import` finding your the library. Something like

```
import unittest.mock
import sys
with unittest.mock.patch('sys.path', []):
    try:
        import derp
    except ImportError:
        pass
    if 'derp' not in sys.modules:
        raise Exception('missing derp')
```